# Need to iterate through a instance of a rails database like an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a relation in my rails database and I get one instance of my relation. I then need to determine how much of that instance is filled in. I do this by counting the nils in the relation but I don't know how to do this through code. I know about the .each loop but that makes me state the fields and i need something more like an array. This is what i have so far

```
@survey_data = Surveyprofile.find_by(:user_id => @user.user_id)

@counter = 0
@index = 0
@survey_data.each do |d|
   //i need something like

   if d[index].nil? == false
          @counter = @counter +1
       end
   @index++
 end
```

does anyone know how to express this??
(this is all done in the controller by the way)

Comment: If you are counting something based on how many relations there are (if relations are nil? or not), I think `@pp.count` would work.

Comment: first of all `index++` doesnt work on Ruby, try `index += 1`, second, could you effort a bit more to describe your question?

Comment: i'm getting an error saying there is no method "count". for future usage, how would i go about, say counting the number of fields that held a specific value?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It would help if you used meaningful variable names. Stuff like `@pp` doesn't mean anything to people other than you.

Comment: The bigger picture is that the user is filling out a survey and i need to show how much the user has filled out. I need to count how many fields have had data entered in them.

Comment: Also, you should keep logic like this inside your models.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. For your initial question, I would put `count = @pp.(insert plural relation name here).count`. For your second question, I would put `count = @pp.(insert plural relation name here).where((insert field name here): (insert value here)).count`. Please give me some more information (i.e. the blanks above) so I can submit a formal answer.

Comment: Hey Ryan, i tried your solution with this 
$hind = @survey_data.(Surveyprofiles).count
and i am getting an uninitialized constant error. 

This is probably a silly question but what more information would you like. I'd be happy to give it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this approach, but it should work.

**survey_profile.rb:**

```
class SurveyProfile < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.number_of_empty_answers(user_id)
    user_survey = SurveyProfile.find_by_user_id(user_id)
    count = 0
    user_survey.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value|
      count += 1 if attr_value.nil?
    end
    return count
  end
```

**survey_profiles_controller.rb:**

```
SurveyProfile.number_of_empty_answers(@user.id)
```

The class method `number_of_empty_answers` counts the answers the user has not filled. Then you call that method from your controller.

Note that it doesn't have to be a class method. It can also be an instance method. You can find the instance first in the controller and then call the method on it.

Since you're iterating through the attributes hash, you can get more fancy and build an array of field names that have not been empty. But if you just want the count, the above should work.

Comment: hey that worked, thanks so much. This community rocks.